# Cygwin x64 - linker was not configured to use sysroots

Tags: c, windows, cygwin

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots
collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
makefile:7: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «make»
make: *** [make] Ошибка 1
```

Я просто пытаюсь собрать для x86 приложение в Cygwin x64 (я бы мог использовать Cygwin x86, но инсталлер все-равно грузит мне x64 o_o, или же Cygwin86 обращается к Cygwin64, не суть)